# Importing data using vba

Tags: vba

My aim is using inputbox to get the data path (xlsx) from the user and then add a new worksheet based on the input. However, I don't know how to write the code.

I try the following code

```
Dim file As String

file = Application.InputBox("Please enter your file location", "File Import")
Worksheets.Add(file)
```

The code does not work and states that the method 'Add' of object sheet failed

Can someone tell me what my mistake is and correct me? Thanks a lot

Comment: You are trying to add a string.

Comment: You want to add a Worksheet to a Workbook or a new Workbook?

Comment: If you want the user to provide a file path then `Application.GetOpenFilename` would be much better than `InputBox`

Comment: @FunThomas add a worksheet to a workbook